# How to persist uni-directional @ManyToMany entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

There are two entities, entity A that has `@ManyToMany` annotation and knows about entity B.

```
@Entity
class EntityA {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "entity_a_entity_b", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_entity_a"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_entity_b"))
    private Set<EntityB> entitiesB = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
class EntityB {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

I'd like to be able to persist an entity B when it's already created or create a new one when it's not. The format of the JSON file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "This is new Entity A",
  "entitiesB": [
    {
      "name": "This is new Entity B"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "This entity B already exists"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the end, the save method is called with a single line `entityARepository.save(entityA)`, the result of this operation is detached entity passed to persist. Do you have any directions on how to do it correctly? It's a Spring Boot application so it's saved via the REST API.

Comment: Its fairly simple. Not the exact match but you will get the idea from here https://github.com/ajkr195/ThymeleafDynamicFields

Comment: @AjayKumar Could you provide an answer here?

Comment: If the example I provided helped, there is no need of answer and bloat SO. Did that sample help you by the way?

Comment: @AjayKumar It did not. There is no `@ManyToMany` relationship and it's not performed as I wish in the above example with the JSON structure provided.

Comment: Your question is about persisting @OneToMany entities. Isn't it?

Comment: @AjayKumar Fixed the summary, sorry.

Comment: How are you assigning EntityB an ID value if it is new? That is missing in the code you provided, as is the exceptions/problems you get with what you are doing. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing for options and examples

Comment: @Chris I do use `@GeneratedValue` annotation with `GenerationType.AUTO` strategy.

Comment: Do you want the EntityB with id 1 values overwritten in the DB with the JSON values? If so, use jpa merge. Spring seems to try to take on far too much JPA provider duties, and checks if it has an ID set or not to decide if it should call persist or merge - recommendation is to always search for existing entities yourself, and then use those references in your new entity (so they are attached and managed already). You may have to implement your own save method to call merge directly - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: So I always passed entityB with an ID in case it exists in the database, but without the ID in case it's not. I wanted to persist the entityB without ID automatically and use it in the entityA the same with already existing entityB. In my case when I do have an entityB with the ID and try to save entityA that has already this entityB in the set an exception is thrown informing about the detached entity.

To assume you suggest to retrieve all entitiesB by the passed ids and then use those objects as a reference and pass them once again to the entityA set?

Comment: @Reddi are you using a transaction whereever you are calling `entityARepository.save(entityA)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It's enough to retrieve entitiesB via their repository and pass retrieved objects to the set before saving entityA.